# Pyramid redirect in event handler

Tags: python, pyramid

Once a user logs for a first time in my application he has to do some selections. I do it by redirecting him to the 'configuration page'. These selections are crucial for whole webpage existence so the application shouldn't do anything before submitting them.
I want to make a request listener that would check whether user has those selections set and if not, it will redirect him to the proper page.
I have done it using:

```
@subscriber(NewRequest)
def has_preferences_set(event):
    request = event.request
    user = request.user
    if not user.preferences:
        raise HTTPFound(location=request.route_url('set_my_preferences'))
```

However I have few problems in it. First, is that this event is actually called 6 times on a single request (what is more, none of them are for actual request, 2 are for static files, 4 are for pyramid_toolbar). The second is that after redirecting I get this error:

> Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete

Answer (score 2):

Take a look into [todopyramid](https://github.com/indypy/todopyramid). It redirects new and existing users with invalid preferences to an account page to set up their user preferences. At every subsequent login valid user preferences will be ensured again.

todopyramid

- [redirects new users to an account page](https://github.com/indypy/todopyramid/blob/master/todopyramid/views.py#L213)
- [updates user preferences within account view](https://github.com/indypy/todopyramid/blob/master/todopyramid/views.py#L248)
- [ensures at every login that user preferences are in a valid state](https://github.com/indypy/todopyramid/blob/master/todopyramid/views.py#L199)
- [encapsulates validation logic for user preferences in user model](https://github.com/indypy/todopyramid/blob/master/todopyramid/models.py#L122)

You might customize validation logic to your needs. todopyramid is working well and encapsulates the concept you need into common models and views. No magic event handlers required.

todopyramid even has a

- [Demo page](http://demo.todo.sixfeetup.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the redirection fail, it's because you have in infinite redirection. When you load your route 'set_my_preferences', your event is triggered and will redirect again.

Regarding the 6 requests, it's true that all these requests, when in dev, are served by Pyramid. In production however, the static files will be (should be) served by the server in front (eg. nginx), and the toolbar won't be served.

Also note that it's heavy on the database to load user preferences in another table for each request. You should probably cache it or something if you really need it every request.

And it's a weird state you have here. Some users not having preferences and others having preferences. You should probably insert default preferences for all the users, and allow them to change those. You will avoid a lot of possible errors and also reduce the number of "if not user.preference" in your application.